# Progressbar with keyframes not working on WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, progress-bar

I am switching from Shopify to WordPress code. I can't seem to get the progress bar to work.

[See the correct progress bar here, this is on shopify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzTCO.png)

This is the code:

```
    <div class="p-obsidan-vs-obsidian">
      <div class="p-obsidan-vs-spectitle">30 kg</div>
      <div class="progress-element neutral-obsidian-power">
        <div class="progress-container"> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-obsidan-vs-name">Test123</div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-obsidan-vs-other">
      <div class="p-obsidan-vs-spectitle">22 kg</div>
      <div class="progress-element neutral-other-power">
        <div class="progress-container"> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="p-obsidan-vs-name">test22</div>
    </div>
```

```
progress {
  opacity: 0;
}

.progress-element {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 0 2px;
}

.progress-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background: #f6953d;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.progress-obsidian-power .progress-container::before {
  animation: progress-obsidian-power 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.progress-other-power .progress-container::before {
  animation: progress-other-power 1s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes progress-obsidian-power {
  to {
    width: 80%;
  }
}    

@keyframes progress-other-power {
  to {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? I think it has something to do with

".progress-obsidian-power .progress-container::before"

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbsQR.png)

Tried changing `".progress-obsidian-power .progress-container::before"`
to `".progress-obsidian-power, .progress-container::before"`

But that makes all the progressbars the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please take a look at this code. Maybe it can be helpful for you. I made some CSS changes.

```css
.progress {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .progress-element {
    width: 350px;
    margin: 0 0 2px;
  }
  
  .progress-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 14px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    background: #f6953d;
    border-radius: 6px;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  
  .progress-obsidian-power .progress-bar {
    animation-name: progress-obsidian-power;
  }
  
  .progress-other-power .progress-bar {
    animation-name: progress-other-power;
  }
  
  @keyframes progress-obsidian-power {
    to {
      width: 80%;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes progress-other-power {
    to {
      width: 45%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="p-obsidan-vs-obsidian">
        <div class="p-obsidan-vs-spectitle">30 kg</div>
        <div class="progress-element progress-obsidian-power">
          <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-obsidan-vs-name">Test123</div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="p-obsidan-vs-other">
        <div class="p-obsidan-vs-spectitle">22 kg</div>
        <div class="progress-element progress-other-power">
          <div class="progress-container">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-obsidan-vs-name">test22</div>
      </div>
```